# Correct way to insert data in column defined as json in migration in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, phpmyadmin

I am working in api development in laravel recently and I am new to json data and api development.

I've defined a column as json like this:

```
$table->json('model_info');
```

Now, I've sent following data from postman.

```
{
    "key":"Size",
    "value":"XL"
}
```

After saving the data in database, I've got following response.

```
"vehicle_model": "{\"key\":\"Size\",\"value\":\"XL\"}",
```

I'm not getting correct data and following error in phpmyadmin.

[image]

I don't know what's going wrong and unable to figure it out.

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Which version of phpMyAdmin are you running? It seems to be this issue: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13497

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your model like this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'model_info' => 'array',
];
```

Read the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)